# Shift array by 1 bit

Tags: assembly, x86

So, I have byte array from 5 elements like this:

```
00000000 00000000 10000001 00000001 10000010
```

Suppose that adress of the array is in esi.
So, I do this command: `shr dword ptr [esi + 1],1` and I want to get this result:

```
00000000 00000000 01000000 10000000 11000001
```

But I get this result:

```
00000000 10000000 11000000 00000000 01000001
```

So, can somebody explain me how can I get what I want to get, and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use RCR instead.

Comment: X86 is little-endian, but you want to treat the bytes as big-endian. So you have two choices: shift each byte one at a time in a loop, using RCR as @Hans suggested, or use MOVBE to load the big endian data into a register, shift it, and use MOVBE to write it back to memory. (Be sure to check CPUID to find out if your CPU has the MOVBE instruction.)

Comment: A better suggestion would be to define the data in little-endian byte order, as expected on an x86 CPU, unless there is some external constraint on the data format that requires that it be defined this way.

Comment: To handle 5 bytes, do the first 4 as a dword, then the last 1.  `rcl` or better `adc reg,reg` is more efficient on modern CPUs to shift CF into the low position.

Comment: Or of course you can load both parts (with `mov` and `movzx`) and `shld` / `shl`.